# UIWebView init in LandScape Mode has "black color part" in right side of screen in iOS 4.1

Tags: ios, uiwebview, landscape, ios4

I have a UIWebView and here is code to init webview:

```
webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

after that I have an sub class of UIViewController with a view. This is init code of that subclass: (We called It is **DetailViewController**)

```
//this is Init method of DetailViewController that contain UIWebView
//self mean DetailViewController

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

// some code to change view frame of view (view of DetailViewController) depend on rotation

// code init webView code here... and resize frame of webview to fill full parrentView

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I have tableView and when I select cell --> push DetailViewController. Everything OK when I select cell on Poitrant mode but when I select cell on Landscape mode --> my webView (just Init) look so strange. It  has "black color part" in right side of screen like discribe below:

|  white space of webview || ***black area*** |  <-- my webview in landscape.

One thing important that is this issue only happen on iOS 4.1 (real device), I test on iOS 4.3 and 5.0, everthing is OK (both is landscape and poitrain).

How to fix this bug? I want my app can support iOS 4.1. Thank in advance.

Comment: If you want to get help, try to accept answers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very very simple indeed.
After you have created the UIWebView called "mywebview", paste the code below

```
[mywebview loadHTMLString:@"<body style=\"width:100%;\"></body>" baseURL:nil];
```

:)